# Show that a matrix expression is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume $A$ is an $n$x$n$ matrix and is idempotent. Show that the matrix $\frac{1}{2}I-A$ is invertible and provide an expression for its inverse.

Not sure where to start. I know that an idempotent matrix on its own is not invertible unless it is the identity matrix.

Comment: What are the possible eigenvalues of $A$? What are the possible eigenvalues of $\frac{1}{2} I - A$?

Comment: try $B = a + bA$ as a candidate for the inverse.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Expand and simplify $\left(\frac 12 I - A \right)^2$ to get a multiple of the identity.

Comment: Not sure what I did wrong, I didn't get a multiple of the identity.                               
$(\frac{1}{2}I-A)^2\rightarrow$ 

$(\frac{1}{2}I-A)(\frac{1}{2}I-A)\rightarrow$

$\frac{1}{4}I-IA+A^2\rightarrow$

$\frac{1}{4}I-A+A^2\rightarrow$

$\frac{1}{4}I-A+A\rightarrow$

$\frac{1}{4}I$

Comment: @jemdo that *is* a multiple of the identity, namely $1/4$ times $I$.

Comment: Haha true, i'm dumb. What would the inverse be then?

Comment: @jemdo You're looking for a matrix $B$ such that $(A-\frac{1}{2}I)B = I$. You've seen that $(A-\frac{1}{2}I)(A-\frac{1}{2}I) = \frac{1}{4}I$. What's your best conjecture for what $B$ should be?